# php5-fpm segfault error 6 in libpcre.so.3.13.1

Tags: ubuntu, segmentation-fault, pcre, php

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 server with PHP 5.5.9, Apache 2.4, varnish, php-fpm and mod_proxy_fcgi.

I have own small template language written in PHP, after migrate from old php 5.2 to php 5.5 everything seems to be ok, but in some cases i have this bug, when a i try render (preg_replace_callback function) template with size 9691 bytes or more php crash. (dmesg output  php5-fpm segfault error 6 in libpcre.so.3.13.1). Small template size is ok.

So, documentation say try change pcre.backtrack_limit and pcre.recursion_limit, so i try it small, middle, extreme value (1000000000) but without efect.

System is up-to-date, is there possible howto increase stack size per proces od thread?

Can anyone help? (sorry for my bad english) F.

Comment: I don't think that increasing the backtrack or the recursion limits is the key of your problem. Most of the time when one of these limits is reached, the pattern is badly designed. I suggest you to edit your post with the pattern.

Comment: New information, testing same code and same configuration under 32bit php running OK (on windows also in linux).

Comment: Ubuntu report crash in apport (/var/log/apport.log), is there way howto encode coredump?ERROR: apport (pid 7004) Tue Mar 24 14:06:06 2015: called for pid 6894, signal 11, core limit 0
ERROR: apport (pid 7004) Tue Mar 24 14:06:06 2015: executable: /usr/sbin/php5-fpm (command line "php-fpm:\ pool\ testing")
ERROR: apport (pid 7004) Tue Mar 24 14:06:06 2015: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 7004) Tue Mar 24 14:06:06 2015: apport: report /var/crash/_usr_sbin_php5-fpm.5002.crash already exists and unseen, doing nothing to avoid disk usage DoS
^C

Answer (score 2):

I also found this same problem, and I solved it setting

pcre.recursion_limit=1000

in /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

Then restarting php5-fpm

Hope it helps!

Comment: You saved my day friend... For reference, here's the reason as stated in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php#ini.pcre.recursion-limit) : "PCRE's recursion limit. Please note that if you set this value to a high number you may consume all the available process stack and eventually crash PHP (due to reaching the stack size limit imposed by the Operating System)." You can check the stack size of the OS by `ulimit -s`